# Matlab Read Tif File shows Error "Cannot handle different values per sample for "BitsPerSample"."

Tags: matlab, tiff

I have a tif file that I can view it from Windows Photos App. You can download it from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n28qvnbbolzoxp0/TifImg.tif?dl=0).
I tried to load it to Matlab using `imread` function, however it shows an error below.

TIFF library error - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Cannot handle different values per sample for
"BitsPerSample".'

I then further looking into the file's profile and find that the BitDepth and BitsPerSample value seems not correct. Also, the MaxSample value looks weird.
[image]

By checking the Matlab buildin tiff file profile, I learned that for a RGB image, BitDepth should be 24 and BitsPerSample should be [8,8,8]. However, when I tried to explicitly change them, I still get the same error.

```
fname = 'TifImg.tif';
info = imfinfo(fname);
% Explicitly Assign Correct Value to BitDepth and BitsPerSample (still doesn't work)
for i = 1: length(info)
    info(i).BitDepth = 24;
    info(i).BitsPerSample = [8 8 8];
end

% Read Tif Image 
frame = imread(fname, 1, 'Info', info);
imshow(frame,[])
```

I hope someone can help me to load this image to Matlab and point me which profile I should change to successfully load the file.

Comment: Can you verify that the image did not break on the way form your phone to matlab? Take the one you have in MATLAB and copy it to your phone, can it still read it? I just tried several programs and none could read the image.

Comment: The TIF file is corrupt. The last value of the `BitsPerSample` tag is overlapping with the first value of the `StripOffsets` tag (3092). The second `BitsPerSample` value is also not correct.

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks. Is there any way I can fix it and read to Matlab? I can verify Windows Photo can still open it which makes me think that I may be able to open it as well.

Comment: @cgohlke I tried to fix it by setting BitPerSample to [8 8 8] but still doesn't work. It looks like even I changed that info structure, Matlab still read image incorrectly.

Comment: If you just want to read the image data from this one corrupt TIFF file, read `StripByteCounts` bytes from `StripOffsets` in the file into an array of shape [3, `ImageWidth`, `ImageLength`] and dtype uint8.

Comment: @cgohlke would it be possible you can write an example? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @cgohlke Can you write me an example to read this file? I have started the bounty and will grant to you if your answer can solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the file seemed to be corrupt. I was also unable to open it with gimp or other programs. So here is a hack. You get the size from the header with imfinfo (height by width by 3 colors), then you read the file from the end. A bit of reordering and the image is salvaged. I don't know about the large BitsPerSample you have in the header, if you use [8,8,8] you have the exact length you need. If you use larger color depth etc you don't have enough numbers in the file to fill the 520x696 pix image.

```
info = imfinfo('TifImg.tif');
fid = fopen('TifImg.tif','r');
s = fread(fid,'uint8=>uint8');
fclose(fid);
len = info.Height*info.Width*3;
data = s(length(s)-len+1:end);
img = reshape(data,3,info.Width,info.Height);
img = permute(img,[3,2,1]);
figure;
imshow(img)
```

[image: fixed image]

Comment: Smart answer. I have only one question before awarding you the bounty. Actually, I am trying to read multi page tifs in the same size. I tried your way to read it but get some weired results. Can you help? Here is my code: 

info = imfinfo(fname);
numofFrames = length(info);
fid = fopen(fname,'r');
s = fread(fid,'uint8=>uint8');
fclose(fid);
len = info(1).Height*info(1).Width*3*numofFrames;
data = s(length(s)-len+1:end); 

imgStacks = reshape(data,numofFrames, 3,info(1).Width,info(1).Height);
imgStacks = permute(imgStacks,[4,3,2,1]);

implay(imgStacks)

Comment: are all frames in uint8? can you link an example?

Comment: Yes the image is just one frame from this multi-page tif file. Here is the link. Thanks!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oi8t10z0n57l8t7/imagestacks.tif?dl=0

Comment: your data samples are s(2797:end), I am looking into this

Comment: This requires heavy detective work. I can get some images this way but their color seems off, and if you take ii = 450 the picture is mashed up. 
fname = 'imagestacks.tif';
info = imfinfo(fname);
numofFrames = length(info);
fid = fopen(fname,'r');
s = fread(fid,'uint8=>uint8');
fclose(fid);
data = s(2797:end);
len = info(1).Height*info(1).Width*3;
figure;
for ii = 1:4
    start = (ii-1)*len+1;
    finish = start+len-1;
    img = reshape(data(start:finish),3,info(1).Width,info(1).Height);
    img = permute(img,[3,2,1]);
    imshow(img)
    title(ii)
    pause
end

Comment: and you can use filesize field to know how many samples to take from end of file

Comment: May I know what this line of code means:
s(length(s)-len+1:end);

Comment: length(s) is how many numbers you have in s, header + image. length(s)-len is the last header number. the next number s(length(s)-len+1 is the first number of your image. then :end means from this point to the end